# Cypher zip collections

Tags: neo4j, cypher

If I have two collections, how might I zip them together?

```
with [1,2,3] as nums, ['a', 'b', 'c'] as letters
... wat do? ...
return zipped // [{a: 1}, {b: 2}, {c: 3}]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It may not be possible to dynamically assign map keys (e.g., using the items in `letters`). But this query will return something similar to what you want (using collections instead of maps):

```
WITH [1,2,3] as nums, ['a', 'b', 'c'] as letters
RETURN EXTRACT(i IN RANGE(0, LENGTH(nums) - 1) | [letters[i], nums[i]]) AS result;
```

The result is:

```
[["a",1],["b",2],["c",3]]
```

Comment: I was just about to answer this question, but then ran into a meta-question.   See this link - can you elaborate?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29265673/constructing-a-map-doesnt-permit-indexed-collection-as-map-key

Comment: I found this to also work pretty well:

WITH [1,2,3] as nums, ['a', 'b', 'c'] as letters
RETURN EXTRACT(i IN RANGE(0, LENGTH(nums) - 1) | {letter: letters[i], num: nums[i]}) AS result;