# Output all direct neighbours in a JSON object

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Is it possible to write a query in Cypher to format the output of the following query into a JSON object?

```
MATCH (n:Artist{name:'Metallica'})-[r]->(m:Album)
RETURN {node: n, neighbours: { type(r): collect(m) }}
```

Of course, this is not a valid Cypher query. I'm trying to see if there's any way to write a query that generates the concept proposed here? One another problem (other than `type(r):`) is with `m` and it needs to be grouped by `type(r)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Gabor Szarnyas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41907445/4989460) said, in the current implementation of the cypher it is impossible to do exactly as you wish. But you can do it using user defined procedure [`apoc.map.fromPairs`](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_map_functions) from [`APOC`](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures) library:

```
MATCH (n:Artist {name:'Metallica'})-[r]->(m:Album)
WITH n, type(r) AS relType, collect(m) AS albums
WITH n, collect([relType, albums]) as pairs
CALL apoc.map.fromPairs( pairs ) YIELD value as neighbours
RETURN { node: n, neighbours: neighbours }
```

Comment: Thanks, it's just that it seems in neo4j 3.1 it should be `RETURN apoc.map.fromPairs( pairs )` without `CALL`.

Answer (score 2):

You can construct a map using [map literals](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.1/cypher/syntax/lists/#_literal_maps). According to its documentation:

> From Cypher, you can also construct maps. Through REST you will get JSON objects; in Java they will be `java.util.Map<String,Object>`.

However, you have to specify the keys in the map in advance - you cannot use variables/expressions (such the value of `type(r)`) as keys. The closest I could get to your requirements is the following:

```
MATCH (n:Artist {name:'Metallica'})-[r]->(m:Album)
WITH n, type(r) AS albumType, collect(m) AS albums
RETURN { node: n, works: collect({ type: albumType, albums: albums }) }
```

(The query is syntactically correct, but I did not test it on any data.)

See also this related question: [Cypher query with literal map syntax & dynamic keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32622805/cypher-query-with-literal-map-syntax-dynamic-keys/)