# How to evaluate a value as a variable in row returned by neo4j?

Tags: json, neo4j, formatting, cypher

I would like to obtain results that I could parse in this way:

```
{ 'nodes' : [ key : { 'property' : ... }, ... # data about nodes  ] 
, 'paths' : [ { .. }, {...} # here go the data about relationships ]  }
```

that is, I want:

- the key in nodes to be the **value of a property** of the node -  as example, key can be the id of the node itself;

If possible, also to format the result as:

- nodes as list of all nodes in the query
- paths as a list of relationships in the query.

I tried:

```
MATCH (d:Label_1)-[r:Rel_type]-(t:Label_2)
        where d.uid = '""" + uid + """'
        with d, r, t
        # how to evaluate d.uid as variable?
        # Return d.uid 
        #
        # collating nodes and paths ?
        # Return [d, t] as nodes, [d, r, t] as paths 
        # Return collect([d, t]) as nodes, [d, r, t] as paths
```

but it does not do it quite right.
I find two problems:

- how to evaluate the property value as a variable in returning results?
- how to have two "separated" tables in the data, so that I could format
  as a, say, json shown above ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Output all direct neighbours in a JSON object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41906377/output-all-direct-neighbours-in-a-json-object)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [apoc procedure library](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_map_functions) it allows you to construct maps programmatically. With plain cypher you can only use fixed keys for map keys.

Something like this should work.

```
MATCH (n:Label)
WITH collect([n.key, properties(n)]) as data
RETURN {'nodes' : apoc.map.fromPairs(data) }
```