# How to aggregate an aggregated list in Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher, aggregation

Basically, I am asking how to complete the following Cypher query:

```
    unwind([[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2]]) as val
    ...
    return ...
```

, so that I can get the following results:

```
    +-----------------+
    | {1:1, 2:2, 3:3} |
    +-----------------+
    | {4:4, 2:2}      |
    +-----------------+
```

For each row `val`, it counts the occurrence of each element in `val`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use characters in the lists as they make the results much easier to comprehend.

```
UNWIND [['a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c'], ['d', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'b', 'b']] as list
WITH list AS list1, list AS list2
UNWIND list2 AS element
WITH list1, element, COUNT(element) AS count
RETURN list1 AS list, COLLECT(element) AS values, COLLECT(count) AS counts
```

This results in:

```
╒══════════════════╤═════════╤═════════╕
│list              │values   │counts   │
╞══════════════════╪═════════╪═════════╡
│[a, b, b, c, c, c]│[c, a, b]│[3, 1, 2]│
├──────────────────┼─────────┼─────────┤
│[d, d, d, d, b, b]│[b, d]   │[2, 4]   │
└──────────────────┴─────────┴─────────┘
```

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29262918/cypher-zip-collections) states that

> It may not be possible to dynamically assign map keys

But it provides a nice alternative in creating two-element lists. Using this approach, the query becomes this:

```
UNWIND [['a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c'], ['d', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'b', 'b']] as list
WITH list AS list1, list AS list2
UNWIND list2 AS element
WITH list1, element, COUNT(element) AS count
WITH list1 AS list, COLLECT(element) AS values, COLLECT(count) AS counts
RETURN
  list,
  EXTRACT(i IN RANGE(0, LENGTH(values) - 1) | [values[i], counts[i]]) AS occurrences
```

This gives:

```
╒══════════════════╤════════════════════════╕
│list              │occurrences             │
╞══════════════════╪════════════════════════╡
│[a, b, b, c, c, c]│[[c, 3], [a, 1], [b, 2]]│
├──────────────────┼────────────────────────┤
│[d, d, d, d, b, b]│[[b, 2], [d, 4]]        │
└──────────────────┴────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: I think it is already elegant enough. I will accept it. Thanks!

Comment: @JoeyZhang you're welcome. I found a way to zip lists in another Stack Overflow question, so please check my answer again.